# parsing arithmetic expression in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I know how to use **stack** to process an arithmetic expression string like `(1 + 2) * 3'. Is there a typical Scheme solution to this issue?

Comment: to clean my question: a user inputs an arithmetic expression with +, -, *, /, ), and (, of course not Lisp style but daily ones like `1 + 3 * (3 - 2)', and the Racket program needs to evaluate its result value. I want to know how Racketors implement the functionality: is there any specific function or lib for it?

Comment: okay, I updated my answer to refer to the parser example that's included with Racket.

Comment: I have figured out an algorithm which transforms an *infix* arithmetic expression into a *binary expression tree*, which is a better solution. I will post my algorithm soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell what question you're asking. In Scheme (or Racket), you'd almost certainly write such an evaluator "directly", like this:

- for E1 * E2, return (eval E1) times (eval E2)
- for E1 + E2, return (eval E1) plus (eval E2)

... so the evaluator is going to be literally three lines long.

Note that in this definition, there's no need to keep track of a stack explicitly (of course, you 
can do the same thing in any other language--you'd use an explicit stack only if you wanted to write
the evaluator in the form of a loop, and didn't want to separate the parsing step).

To parse the expression, you need... well, you probably want a parser. If you're using Racket,
you could take a look at the calculator example that comes with Racket in `collects/parser-tools/examples/calck.rkt`.  It handles everything you describe. I could paste it all in here, but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Scheme solution is to parse the expression, and then use a stack like you already know how to do.